# TensorFlow Word Embedding Not Making Sense

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, word-embedding

I am not understanding how the `VocabularyProcessor` works in tensorflow. I loaded in glove encodings and am mapping my data to it with the following code.

```
vocab_processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(max_document_length)
pretrain = vocab_processor.fit(vocab)
X_np_data = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(X_data)))
```

But comparing the outputs to the vocab index I don't think the results make sense.

For example, in the input data there's this

```
X_data[1]
Out[84]: "is upset that he ca n't update his facebook by texting it and might cry as a result school today also blah ! "
```

Word indexes

```
X_np_data[1]
Out[85]: 
array([  22, 3091,   32,   83,  132,   31, 1741,  203,  380,  123, 1971,
         23], dtype=int64)
```

But, if we look at the vocab index that those numbers are referencing it's not the same as what's in the sentence

```
vocab[22]
Out[86]: 'de'
vocab[3091]
Out[87]: 'entiendo'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I not understanding how this works?

**Edit**
I think I am not understanding how this works and have not been able to find a good example online. I assumed it would be mapped back to the index of the vocab list of the word and then that would be used to reference an embeddings placeholder where row i is the embedding for word i in the vocab list. But looking at just `len(vocab)` and `len(pretrain.vocabulary_)` they don't even have the same number of entries. vocab has 1193514 and pretrian has 1138921.